# mysql to search in multiple quantity

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem. I'm building a Client Information System with PHP and MYSQL. One of the feature of the application is to allow users to search for the name by typing ic number in multiple input. For example, information stored in the database:

ID   : 1 
NAME : John 
IC   : 111

ID   : 2 
NAME : James 
IC   : 222

ID   : 3 
NAME : Sarah 
IC   : 333

---

So, to search the data, in search field (form), i would like to type 111222 , without comma. so is there any ways? Any sql syntax which should i use?

Any help is very much appreciated

---

EDITED

Here is my code for searching function.

```
$ics = $_POST["nokp"]; 
$each =explode(' ',$ics);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT id,nama,nokp from client where nokp in(". implode(',', $each).") group by nama,nokp");
```

Comment: No.  Use multiple fields in the form.

Comment: if ic was always 3 digit ... but no @AbraCadaver is correct

Comment: i can't use multiple fields in the form because the database stored millions of rows in a 'clients' table. i need to search ic number within 200 and  ++ ic number

Comment: no idea what you just tried to explain. the number of db rows has no reliance to the user interface

Comment: The flow is, user copy the group of ic number from microsoft word within 200 rows, and paste inside the search field.

Comment: is each ic number a fixed length?

Comment: i posted a solution below if the answer to my question is **yes**, if its no, then how do you know when one number ends and another starts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ics="111 222 333 444 aaaaaaaaaaaddddddd335555555555"; 

//$each =str_split ($ics,3); 
$each =explode(' ',$ics);
//print_r($each);

$q="SELECT foo from bar where ic in(" . implode("','", $each)."')";

echo $q; //SELECT foo from bar where ic in(111','222','333','444','aaaaaaaaaaaddddddd335555555555')
```

Comment: but if ic number have different type. For example

111, 222, 333, 1234, A111, A 111 B

Comment: then how do you know when one starts and another ends?

Comment: one number ends and another starts by space

Comment: ok easy, explode on space then, the rest you can follow above

Comment: It does not display any output

Comment: update the question, don't post as a comment, the code you are now using

Comment: you have to change it to use your variables

Comment: wait a minute, echo $q show SELECT * from client where nokp in( )

Comment: $ics = $_POST["nokp"];
 require("conn.php"); 
 $each =explode($ics,' ');

 $q="SELECT * from client where nokp in(". implode(',',$each) .")";

 echo $q;

Comment: look above again its `$each =explode(' ',$ics); `  if you need quotes (non intergers) the in need to be updated to

Comment: it's ok if the output are integers, if non integer, it does not display any output.

Comment: where nokp in(". implode(',',$each) .")

Comment: I've found the answer. Only need to add the apostrophe. ('". implode(',',$each) ."')